# Bootstrap - Image overlapping image

Tags: html, grid, overlapping

I need to put an image that is overlapping into my grid.
So the problem is not only that the image does overlap the right border of my grid, also its technically wider than 50% - but the x position starts at 50%.

Please check out the image which is attached to this post.

Can Bootstrap handle such images?
Thanks

PS. stackoverflow does not want me to provide "Bootstrap" as key word ... interesting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the bootstrap img-responsive class in your image?

Comment: I can, if I need to. More interesting would be the general question - if bootstrap does handle objects which are overlapping the grid borders.

Comment: Other question - is there any Bootstrap relevant forum out there?